# Subroutine to convert integer to string MIPS

Tags: mips

I am trying to solve this problem (MARS MIPS):

I have opened a file and the file descriptor is stored in $s5. I would like to make a subroutine to convert integers in an array to char values to be written to a file. The integers are separated by 3 empty array slots, such as 19 0 0 0 20 0 0 0

How would I make this subroutine?

Comment: You have no question, yet this is a Q&A website.  So, ask a specific question about what you're struggling with.

Comment: There's the question, if it was not obvious already

Comment: That much was obvious, of course, but not really appropriate for this website as you're asking for mentoring on writing an entire subroutine (that you apparently haven't started yet), rather asking to solve or address a specific problem.